# PHP: opposite of extends (for parent class)

Tags: php, inheritance, extends

I'm aware of using `extends` but i am wondering what's the best practice for doing the opposite:

I'm having a "parent" class called `c_film` and 2 child classes called `c_wikipedia` and `c_imdb` - they need to access the general settings (`$aOptions`) and functions / error handler from `c_film`.

here's a simplified version:

```
$aOptions = array(
    "wikidata_id"    => "Q63985561"; // the movie is: tenet
    "verbose_output" => true,
    "logging"        => true
);
$o = new c_film( $aOptions );
$aData = $o->load_film(); // scrape wikipedia, scrape imdb, merge data into array
```

these are the requirements:

`c_film` has functions for scraping/parsing/error handling for all child classes/logging/misc which can be used from both child classes

`c_wikipedia` and `c_imdb` can access options / functions from `c_film` and trigger errors

here's my current solution (simplified):

```
class c_film
{
    function __construct( $aOptions )
    {
        $this->aOptions = $aOptions;
    }

    function load_film()
    {
       $o = new c_wikipedia( $this );
       $this->aWikipedia = $o->get_data();

       $o = new c_imdb( $this );
       $this->aImdb = $o->get_data();

       $aData = $this->get_merged_data();
    }   

    private function get_merged_data()
    {
       // process data / merge into one array 
       $aResult = array_merge( $this->aWikipedia, $this->aImdb );
       result $aResult;
    }

    function scrape($url)
    {
        // scrape data / handle 404 / log errors/ html parsing
        // [code here]
        return $html;
    }

    function log($msg, $class, $function)
    {
       // log to file
    }

    function error( Throwable  $t )
    {
         // log error into file
    }
}

class c_wikipedia
{
    function __construct( $oFilm ) // parent class object c_film
    {
        $this->oFilm = $oFilm;
    }

    function get_data()
    {
        try {
          // scrape data from wikipedia
          $aData = $this->get_data();
          $url = $this->get_url_from_wikidata_id();
          $html = $oFilm->scrape($url);
        } catch(Throwable $t ){
          // 
          $oFilm->error( $t );
        }
    }

    private function get_data()
    {
        $oFilm = $this->oFilm;
        $aOptions = $oFilm->aOptions;
        $wikidata_id = $aOptions['wikidata_id'];
        $bLog = $oFilm->aOptions['logging'];
        $output = $oFilm->aOptions['verbose_output'];

        // .. load + parse data
        $url = // determine url
        $msg = "loading data for " . $wikidata_id;
        if($bLog) $oFilm->log($msg, get_class(), __FUNCTION__ ); // log to file including class name and function name
        if($output) echo $msg;

        $html = $oFilm->scrape($url);
        return $aData;
    }
}
```

So - is passing the c_film object to the child classes the best practice or is there a more elegant method?

Comment: The `$oFilm` methods you're calling have no relation to the "film data source" classes, they're just taking arbitrary string data.  To me, it makes more sense to split those into entirely separate helper classes/functions.  Passing the array of options through is fine, but I generally see the passing of `$this` to another object as a code smell.

Comment: i agree about the smell :D that's why i was asking .. however, $oFilm also handles Errors from both classes which is nice too ..

Comment: You could accomplish something similar by throwing exceptions like `{Wikipedia|Imdb}ScrapeException` in `c_wikipedia` wrapping that logic in a try/catch and logging the output.